# AWS Lambda (Node.js) Monitor if website is online

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have a lambda function that checks if a website responds.

If it's offline/unresponsive I will reboot the server.

The problem is that this function I am working with, returns an error because I don't have a SSL certificate installed (it's a vpn server without a domain name, just IP)

> Got error: self signed certificate in certificate chain

What I am trying to achieve: if the server responds, disregard the SSL error and declare it a success.

However I am just starting out in node.js so I would appreciate anyone that can point me in the right direction.

No http:80 port available. Only option is https.

```
function checkWebsite(url, callback) {
  http.get(url, function(res) {
      console.log(url, res.statusCode);
      return callback(res.statusCode === 200);
    })
    .on("error", function(e) {
      return callback(false);
    });
}

exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) {
  checkWebsite(url, (check) => {

    if (!check) {...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would seem you can explicitly prevent SSL verification checks by adding the following parameter:

- `rejectUnauthorized: false`. If not false, the server certificate is verified against the list of supplied CAs. An 'error' event is emitted if verification fails; err.code contains the OpenSSL error code. Default: true

In your code this would become:

```
function checkWebsite(url, callback) {
  options = {
      rejectUnauthorized: false
  };

  http.get(url, options, function(res) {
      console.log(url, res.statusCode);
      return callback(res.statusCode === 200);
    })
    .on("error", function(e) {
      return callback(false);
    });
}
```

Ensure you limit this to only the domain(s) that need this. Alternatively you could try to perform a TCP connection verification (can you connect on port `443` over TCP).

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. If I paste this code into lambda, it throws an error on line 2: options is not defined. Should I write "var options"? Not very familiar with node.js

Comment: Ah yes, apologies :)

Comment: I'll give it a run now :)

Comment: It appears to be performing a 302 (which is a redirect). Is it perhaps going to another path than the one you have specified?